# How to print a list that is a type in a struct

Tags: struct, racket, pretty-print

How can the list-of-terms list be referenced for printing?

I can do this:

```
(~a (student-id a-student)
```

This gives me the student ID, but I want a list of the enrolled terms.

If I try:

```
(~a (student-list-of-terms a-student))
```

I get the error:
*student-list-of-terms: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition*

The definition of **student** is:

```
(define a-student (student pidm list-of-terms list-of-events list-of-withdrawals list-of-courses date-lda date-wdrl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for Racket to know what a `student` is you need to use `struct` to define what a student means. If a student struct has a list-of-terms field, you can then use `student-list-of-terms` to access the list of terms of a student.

Here is an example:

```
#lang racket
(struct student (pidm list-of-terms list-of-events list-of-withdrawals
                      list-of-courses date-lda date-wdrl))

(define a-student
  (student 42
           (list 'term1 'term2)
           (list 'event1 'event2)
           (list 'withdrawal1 'withdrawal2)
           (list 'course1 'course2)
           "a date"
           "another date"))

(student-list-of-terms a-student)
```

Comment: Here is the definition of student I am using:(define-struct student (pidm terms attendance-events courses withdrawal-events lwd lda  )#:transparent). Ah...nevermind...it is a list, but I have it labelled as "terms".

Comment: Then use `(student-terms a-student)`

Comment: Is there a way to reflect on the student struct and get an understanding of the names of the accessors. Now I want to get at the elements in the individual terms, defined as such: (define-struct term (term-number ptrm-code start-date end-date)#:transparent);. Also, what is the difference between 'struct' and 'define-struct'?

Comment: It's historical. The form used to define structs was called `define-struct` (and `define-struct` is still used in the teaching languages) but in recent versions of Racket it is called `struct`. The form `define-struct` wasn't removed though, so it still works.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31146880/23567 for more on how the names are created.

Comment: Thank you. That is good to know. I still am not grokking how to get the term-number, et al. for printing.

Comment: Since a `term` has a field `term-number` you need to use `term-term-number`.